# Why do some cables run at 100M instead of 1000M? Do I need 1000M connection to router if internet speed max is under 100M?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, wireless-access-point

I recently changed my my home network topology from the web of assorted unmanaged switches to a single managed 24port switch.

This led me to discovering 2 cables only run at 100M remaining 10 or so all run at 1000M. Of the two 100M one runs between the switch and router, the other one runs between switch and Wifi AP in my room.

At first I though, well, internet speed is 92M down /20M up so 100M should about cover it, the wifi ap is supposed to be 5GHz 867Mbps+2.4 GHz 300Mbps, but it's used only for internet access and not local lan access so 100M should about do too.

It kept nagging at me though, tried different ports, but it was the cables not the ports. I did some googling suggesting to test the cables. I did and the results only further confuse me:

- the router<--->switch cable tests as 1 wire faulty
- the switch<--->wifi ap cable tests as all wires ok

Do I really need gigabit connection between router and switch if switch is the only device connected to router and the speed of internet is under 100M? I mean I can replace the cable, but if it's still gonna run only at 100M even with 100% cable I'd rather not have to remove ~15m of carpets and redo the cabling, it has been running on this cable for years.

As for the 2nd cable that tests good, could the AP itself or the switch auto "downgrade" the speed since the link is never saturated or is my AP just hosed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your max internet speed is under 100Mbps then you don't need a connection faster than that between your router in switch. However, if it is a bad cable, not only can it slow down your connection, it can also create lag and corrupt data. This will definitely be an issue if you play multiplayer games. The corrupt data will be resent (if TCP and most games aren't) but it adds delay. Another possibility is your router may not support 1000Mbps. You can try running a new cable above the carpet just to test to see if it improves or not. Most new routers support 1000Mbps but not all the older ones do. Same for APs.

Comment: Yeah I guess it makes sense to replace the cable if 1 wire is dead, probably won't have time to do it properly until X-mas week off. Funny thing though I do play online a lot, and my connection is really stable, with sub 30-100ms latency depending where the servers are.

Comment: All 8 wires are used for 1Gbps connections so if just one wire is bad, then it will drop to 100Mbps which is probably why games are running fine still because the remaining 100Mbps wires are fine.